# Unable to get the new file size after overwriting a file with PHP?

Tags: php, image-processing

I have an image that is x bytes on disk.

I process it with `Imagick::thumbnailImage`.

Then I overwrite the orignal with `Imagick::writeImage`.

When I look at the file on disk, it is now y bytes, but using `filesize( image_path )` gives me the original size value of x bytes while that script is still running.  If I execute `filesize( image_path )` afterwards in another script it works fine and return y bytes as the size.

I've tried clearing and destroying the Imagick object after writing the file and that doesn't solve the problem.

What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [clearstatcache](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) function after writing your file.